# Get data from JSON object and array

Tags: android, arrays, json, object

Searching for solution of that. Sample of Java code:

```
public void loadPositions(JSONObject result){
    try {
        JSONObject jObject = result.getJSONObject("points");
        Iterator<String> keys = jObject.keys();
        while (keys.hasNext()) {
            String key = keys.next();
            Log.v("list key", key);

            if(jObject.get(key) instanceof JSONObject) {
                JSONObject innerJObject = jObject.getJSONObject(key);
                String lat = innerJObject.getString("lat");
                String lon = innerJObject.getString("lon");

                Log.i("details", "lat = " + lat + ", " + "lon = " + lon);
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

JSON data:

```
{  
   "points":{  
      "C50D15525":[  
         {  
            "lat":"51.643257329609156",
            "lon":"17.798963651975885"
         },
         {  
            "lat":"51.643257329609156",
            "lon":"17.798963651975885"
         }
      ],
      "BFFCDE4AF":[  
         {  
            "lat":"51.6434779",
            "lon":"17.7993028"
         },
         {  
            "lat":"51.6434779",
            "lon":"17.7993028"
         },
         {  
            "lat":"51.6434779",
            "lon":"17.7993028"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Code above give me only list key, but I want LAT & LON from many points like "BFFCDE4AF" and "C50D15525". I've tried in many ways... JSON data is valid.

Answer (score 0):

You can achive it through this
For example
points.C50D15525["lat"]

but you need to extract json through apply any looping  and associative concept.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the "points" object your JSON has an `Array` object, which you need to get with the `getJSONArray()` method. Loop through the `JSONArray` and get the "lat"  and "lon" objects.

```
public void loadPositions(JSONObject result){
    try {
        JSONObject jObject = result.getJSONObject("points");
        Iterator<String> keys = jObject.keys();
        while (keys.hasNext()) {
            String key = keys.next();
            Log.v("list key", key);

            JSONArray jArray = jObject.getJSONArray(key);
            for (int i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++){
                JSONObject obj = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String lat = obj.optString("lat", "NA"));
                String lon = obj.optString("lon", "NA"));
                Log.i("details","key = " + key + " coor count = " + i + " lat = " + lat + ", " + "lon = " + lon);
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Since I have not tested this, please let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: after while of testing I see something weird... It's gets only few records - in array "BFFCDE4AF" is about 40 records - but I see only half of them.

Comment: @Bushu  :: Please post the JSON that is having trouble in its entirety and I will test that data